# Why I am getting this error in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

There are two pages on our website cloudtrains.com

1. https://cloudtrains.com/hire-remote-developers/
2. When I edit the page and click on revisions same error I received there as well . I am getting this error, tired everything but nothing works. Anyone help me in this

[image]

Comment: It's telling you to check the errors on your server logs. I suggest doing that. Also this isn't a programming question, it's a WordPress usage question. It probably fits better somewhere like here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

this isn't an error from wordpress. It seems that you haven't configured your webserver (apache) properly. Hence, although apache understands the request, it doesn't know how to respond.